# iOS 9: low energy -> do developers have to prepare for that?

Tags: ios, xcode7, ios9

In the WWDC 2015 keynote, it was mentioned that batteries will last one hour longer, and have a low power state that can extend the battery three more hours.

Do iOS App developers have to do anything for this new feature?  Is there something their apps must do (or not do) when in that low battery state?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about that explicitly, but implicitly you probably won't be able to connect to any network or bluetooth device, and some of the visual effects (transitions, motions etc...) will be disabled in that mode – in general you need to handle the lack of resources in application as usually you would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it has nothing to do with 3rd-Party applications and more about iOS itself. Here's an article I found:

http://www.redmondpie.com/how-ios-9-low-power-mode-for-battery-life-saving-works/

Here's another article that seems to confirm it is only for iOS itself (and background processes like downloading, which may effect some apps):
http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/06/08/low-power-mode-in-ios-9/

As far as I'm aware, **none** of this requires any developer interaction. From Apple's perspective that would be a bad idea, since then developers could essentially choose whether or not to comply, and would make their Low Power mode useless (because many developers would not choose to make their app perform worse)

On a side note, I'm happy that iOS 9 will no longer light up my screen if my device is facedown on a table and I get a notification. If you read, there's a few new power-saving features that do not involve the use of the Low Power mode.

Comment: it essentially terminates the ability to conduct background activity... so it definitely does require developer interaction if your app relies on proper background functionality

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the new [discretionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/discretionary) network tasks introduced  with iOS 7 and other APIs that reduce battery life.
Check out the following sessions from WWDC 2014:

[Writing Energy Efficient Code, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#710)

[Writing Energy Efficient Code, Part 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#712)

Answer (score 0):

You can either register for NSNotification for NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChangeNotification

Or use this NSProcessInfo.processInfo().isLowPowerModeEnabled

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LowPowerMode.html

Answer (score 0):

Update for 9.0.2:
I am sorry to say, that the above answer is not correct (anymore). 
When in power mode, apps can't react to push messages anymore, because the corresponding function

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
```

is not called.

I wonder how messaging services go around that? 
Has anybody got any clue?

See also my explicit question - with more details on this matter: 
[IOS9 Push Battery Saver Mode - didReceiveRemoteNotification not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144238/ios9-push-battery-saver-mode-didreceiveremotenotification-not-called)

Comment: I'd love to make a comment, but don't have enough reputation yet. 
I found it important to still add this information, so I choose this way.
I did already ask a new question and added a link - see above. Sorry, I don't get what you mean, Flexicoder.