# IOS9 Push Battery Saver Mode - didReceiveRemoteNotification not called

Tags: sdk, push, ios9, mode, battery-saver

On IOS9 if an iPhone is in battery save mode, the callback

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

is not called. Instead I get the following warning in the console

```
High Priority Push: com.your-company.app - Battery Saver Mode Enabled
```

When using PushKit it does seem to work.

Does anybody else experience this behaviour?

Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, unfortunately, that this is the intended behavior. The documentation about push notifications constantly hedges their reliability. E.g.:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

> Important: Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not
>   guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to
>   notify the user that there is new data available

There are a lot of conditions under which notifications won't be delivered or delivery will be delayed, and sometimes Apple will coalesce multiple notifications and only deliver the last one.

PushKit is a more reliable replacement for applications that want VOIP functionality, where using a notification to ring the user for a call needs better reliability. That's why it's still working in battery-save mode.

In terms of workarounds, it really depends what you're trying to accomplish. One possibility is you can schedule local notifications while your app is running, and those will be more reliable than the standard remote ones.

Comment: I like you answer, Joe Castro. Sorry, for upvoting, I don't have enough reputation, yet. 


When one wants to make a reliable messenger app without VoIP, there seems to be a hard time, to get notified when new messages arrive. If you  want to avoid polling. 
PushKit seems be allowed to VoIP-Apps only.
Are there other conditions - other than power-save mode or multiple notifications, where pushes are not supposed to work?

Comment: Apple seems to have heuristics that they don't want to document (I expect because they don't want people relying on them) for when they decide to not push the notifications. One scenario is when the phone isn't on the network and once it comes back your app may only get the last one. Another reasonable scenario is that Apple decides that your app is sending too many notifications relative to how much the user is actively using the app. Apple's guidance on this generally reads as "Write notifications as though they're reliable, but make sure your app will work if none of them ever arrive".

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Joe. I find that there is a difference in getting no pushes and getting not so many pushes. The last is ok, the first is not ;-)